# POST data not registering in Django custom admin action with intermediate form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to add a custom admin action do my Django model. The goal is to show a form to the user where they can select a group which will get linked to all my selected candidates.

My issue is that the code works in the render part, and the form is shown. However when I click apply my code never enters the `if 'apply' in request.POST` condition. It also seems the code is never called a second time.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**CandidateAdmin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from exem_poi.models import Candidate
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from exem_poi.views.utils import convert_to_wgs84
from exem_poi.models.Candidate import Group

@admin.register(Candidate)
class CandidateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('batiment_construction_id', 'emitters_100m', 'height', 'display_owners', 'is_public')
    list_filter = ('emitters_100m', 'height', 'is_public')
    search_fields = ('batiment_construction_id', 'emitters_100m', 'height', 'is_public')
    readonly_fields = ('centroid',)
    actions = ['assign_to_group']

    def assign_to_group(self, request, queryset):
        # Handle the form submission for assigning candidates to a group
        
        print(request.POST)
        if 'apply' in request.POST:
            group_id = request.POST.get('group_id')
            group = Group.objects.get(id=group_id)
            for candidate in queryset:
                group.candidates.add(candidate)
            self.message_user(request, f'Successfully assigned candidates to group {group.name}')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)

        groups = Group.objects.all()
        context = {'groups': groups, 'candidates': queryset}
        return render(request, 'admin/assign_to_group.html', context)
```

**assign_to_group.html**

```
<!-- admin/assign_to_group.html -->
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="group_id">Select a group:</label>
    <select name="group_id" required>
      {% for group in groups %}
        <option value="{{ group.id }}">{{ group.name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="assign_to_group">
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Apply">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried adding a print to see if the method gets called twice, and it only prints on the first call, so my instinct was to check this side of the code, but I can't seem to find the solution. I have also tried using a simpler template with a basic form but clicking the apply button never triggers the second part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an intermediate page for performing complex action, like form submission, some extra data showing on page etc.

Create an action method **assign_to_group()**, which redirect to intermediate page url and pass **selected object_ids** as a param with url. Registered this url with admin.

Create a view where your render data with form and after form submission you processed action.

admin.py

```
def assign_to_group(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    selected = queryset.values_list("pk", flat=True)
    selected_ids = ",".join(str(pk) for pk in selected)
    intermediate_page_url = "%s?ids=%s" % (reverse("admin:group_assign"), selected_ids)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(intermediate_page_url)


@admin.register(Candidate)
class CandidateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = [assign_to_group]

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path("group-assign/", self.admin_site.admin_view(GroupAssignView.as_view()), name="group_assign"),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls
```

view.py

```
from django.views import View

class GroupAssignView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        # you can get selected object ids for action
        ids = request.GET.get('ids')
        # Now you can do everything like render form with data
        context = dict()
        ...
        return render(request, 'admin/assign_to_group.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.POST
        # After form submission you get form-data , complete your action
        ...

        # finally redirected back to the original change list page.
        return redirect(reverse('admin:<app_name>_candidate_changelist'))
```